# php check if start or if expiry dates are either null or greater/less than todays date

Tags: php, date, date-comparison

I have a foreach loop and I need to add date conditions for optional start and expiry dates.

I'm using this as I need to set up some scheduling, but I can't get this to run.

```
$thedate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
foreach ( $getframe as $frame ){
    if(isset($frame['dateexpire']) && $frame['dateexpire'] <= $thedate || $frame['dateexpire'] == NULL
    || isset($frame['datestart']) && $frame['datestart'] >= $thedate || $frame['datestart'] == NULL ) {
        // get the frames
    }
}
```

`$frames['datestart']` and `$frames['dateexpire']` are either NULL or set in my table as timestamps.

So if either the start date is either NULL or GREATER than the current date, or the expiry date is either NULL or LESS than the current date, the frame should appear.

I guess I'm going about this in totally the wrong, can anyone shed any light on the correct approach

Comment: What are the values in those variables? That matters.

Comment: if they are not NULL, they are timestamps

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is you were comparing timestamps (`$frames['datestart']` and `$frames['dateexpire']`) to a string (`$thedate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`).

Here's a fixed version with some additional improvements.

```
$today = time();
foreach ( $getframe as $frame ){
    if (is_null($frame['datestart']) || is_null($frame['dateexpire']) || $frame['datestart'] > $today || $frame['dateexpire'] < $today) 
       // get the frames
    }
}
```

- I named the variable representing today as `$today` as well, that makes the most sense.
- I use [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) to check for null values

Comment: I can get either the start or expiry to work, but not both together. I've set up 4 frames, each with different date conditions, the first has no start or expiry date, the second has a start date, the third has a expiry date and the 4th has both a start and expiry date.

Comment: Give me a sample set of start and expire dates so I can actually test this.

Comment: I think I've got it, I had to set up a true/false if first for either the start or the end, then ask the existing if statement if start and end are true.